# compare whether 3 factors of a categorical variable are distributed differently

Tags: count-data

For every subject in a study, I have 40 responses that can be: a,b,c.
So it would look somthing like

sub  |  trial | resp 
1              1             a   
1              2             b   
....
50          40         c

I want to check if their occurence rate differs (i.e a is much more frequent than b or c).
Is it correct to sum them up and use a linear model: 
sums ~ factor + (1|subject)

Comment: [Fitting a Poisson GLM mixed model with a random slope and intercept](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27869/fitting-a-poisson-glm-mixed-model-with-a-random-slope-and-intercept)

Comment: Maybe you can share some data (real or example data)?